# Javabeans and JSP 2.0

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans, javabeans

So I'm trying to build a table based on the search results from a database access.

I'm searching for courses, so I have a javabean called CourseJBean, which has a number of fields and the appropriate getters and setters (e.g. for the field 'id', getId() and setId(newId) are used). I also have a javabean called searchJBean, which holds an ArrayList of CourseJBeans (the ArrayList is parametrized). This is me dealing with an unknown number of courses being returned from the search. Then I want to fill a table with a course per row, with each cell with one of the course's properties.

I fill the searchJBean as follows:

```
searchJBean results = new searchJBean();

while (resultSet.next())    {
    CourseJBean course = new CourseJBean();
    course.setId(resultSet.getString(1));
    course.setSection(resultSet.getString(2));
              :
              :
    course.setExam(resultSet.getString(14));
    course.setCredits(resultSet.getString(15));
    results.addCourse(course);
}
```

In my JSP, I have a JSTL for-each loop going on

```
 <c:forEach var="course" items="${requestScope.searchResults.courses}">
```

What I want this to do is to loop through the ArrayList (the field holding it is called 'courses') within the searchJBean (called 'searchResults') and then create a row with each cell holding a different property of the course, e.g.

```
<tr> 
    <td> ${course.id} </td>
    <td> ${course.section} </td>
            :
            :
</tr>
```

Hopefully, this will populate a table with a whole lot of values. The CourseJBean's fields are all of type String, if that matters. I'm using JSP 2.0, JDK 1.6, and Java SE 6 on Netbeans 7.0 with an Apache 7 local server.

However, when I ran it like this, I got an error:

```
May 5, 2011 6:39:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValveinvoke  
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [cirr_search.do] in context with path [/Registrar] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /HTML-JSP/searchResults.jsp at line 55

52:                      
53:  <tr> 
54:      <td> 
55:          ${course.id} 
56:      </td> 
57:      <td> 
58:          ${course.section}


Stacktrace:] with root cause javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: 
        Property 'id' not readable on type java.lang.String     
at javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperty.read(BeanELResolver.java:291)   
at javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperty.access$000(BeanELResolver.java:239) 
at ....
```

(and so on. If you want the complete log, I can paste it later.)

I think this meant that it's retrieving 'course' as a String, not a CourseJBean, which is why it can't find the property 'id'. I wasn't sure why this was happening, so after a bunch of Googling, I went with adding  tags:

In the header of the page (between the head tags):

```
<jsp:useBean id="searchResults" scope="request" class="searchJBean"/>
```

At the beginning of the loop, i.e. after the  tag:

```
<jsp:useBean id="course" scope="page" class="CourseJBean"/>
```

Both CourseJBean.java and searchJBean.java reside in the default package (for now -- I'm learning). I wasn't entirely sure how to use the "class" attribute, so that's what I put. But now when I run it, I get this error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 14 in the jsp file: /HTML-JSP/searchResults.jsp
searchJBean cannot be resolved to a type
11:         <%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
12:         <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript/searchResults.js"></script>
13:         <title>cirr_search results</title> 
14:         <jsp:useBean id="searchResults" scope="request" class="searchJBean"/>
15:     </head> 
16:
```

which is repeated three times, and then this:

```
An error occurred at line: 52 in the jsp file: /HTML-JSP/searchResults.jsp
CourseJBean cannot be resolved to a type
49:                 <!-- Build the rows. -->
50: 
51:                 <c:forEach var="course" items="${requestScope.searchResults.courses}">
52:                     <jsp:useBean id="course" type="CourseJBean" scope="page" class="CourseJBean"/>
53:                     <tr>
54:                         <td>
55:                             ${course.id}
```

which also repeats three times, and is followed by a stack trace that starts with

```
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:95)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:457)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:374)
```

and continues for another ten or fifteen lines.

So my questions are:

What does this mean?
What is a 'type'?
Do I need to use  tags even in JSP 2.0? Shouldn't it be able to find them?
The original error -- why would I get a String?

And most importantly, how do I fix this?

EDIT:
The servlet is boring, so here's (part of) the DB access to make the CourseJBean:

```
List<CourseJBean> results = new ArrayList<CourseJBean>();

while (resultSet.next())    {
    CourseJBean course = new CourseJBean();
    course.setId(resultSet.getString(1));
    course.setSection(resultSet.getString(2));
    course.setTitle(resultSet.getString(3));
    course.setProf(resultSet.getString(4));
    course.setProfID(resultSet.getString(5));
    course.setDept(resultSet.getString(6));
    course.setDays(resultSet.getString(7));
    course.setTime(resultSet.getString(8));
    course.setArea(resultSet.getString(9));
    course.setDiv(resultSet.getString(10));
    course.setRoom(resultSet.getString(11));
    course.setReg(resultSet.getString(12));
    course.setMax(resultSet.getString(13));
    course.setExam(resultSet.getString(14));
    course.setCredits(resultSet.getString(15));
    results.add(course);
}

return results;
```

The CourseJBean has the following fields:

```
private String id;          
private String section;
private String title;
private String prof;
private String profID;
private String dept;
private String days;
private String time;
private String area;
private String div;
private String room;
private String reg;
private String max;
private String exam;
private String credits;
```

They're all strings because it's easier for me (right now) to just throw them into a table that way.

Here's the code to print the table:

```
<table id="results_table" border="1" cellpadding="5">

    <!--Row headings-->
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td><td>Section</td><td>Title</td><td>Professor (email)</td>
        <td>Department</td><td>Days</td><td>Times</td><td>Area/Div</td>
        <td>Room</td><td>Reg/Max</td><td>Exam</td><td>Credits</td><td></td>
    </tr>

    <!-- Build the rows. -->

    <c:forEach var="course" items="${requestScope.searchResults}">
        <tr>
            <td>${course.id}</td>
            <td>${course.section}</td>
            <td>${course.title}</td>
            <td>${course.prof} (${course.profID})</td>
            <td>${course.dept}</td>
            <td>${course.days}</td>
            <td>${course.time}</td>
            <td>${course.area}</td>
            <td>${course.room}</td> 
            <td>${course.reg}/${course.max}</td>
            <td>${course.exam}</td>
            <td>${course.credits}</td>
            <td><buttonid="dropButton"type="button"value="${course.id}">Drop</button></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>    
</table>
```

When I run it like this, I get the same'PropertyNotFoundException':

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'id' not readable on type java.lang.String
```

I'm not sure where it's getting a string from. If I comment out the forEach loop completely, and just have ${searchResults}, I get this array:

```
[CourseJBean@554210, CourseJBean@16433e4, CourseJBean@18ada25, CourseJBean@f7bd29, CourseJBean@a3cf3e, CourseJBean@7af3e0, CourseJBean@21151e, CourseJBean@1f194d9, CourseJBean@1635a89, CourseJBean@1ccf0ad]
```

which if I understand correctly is an array of references to my CourseJBeans. When I ask for ${searchResults[3]}, it prints

```
CourseJBean@1482aa9
```

which I believe is a reference. So it has an array, but because it's of references, it's reading them as Strings, not references?

Also, if, in my servlet (using the first code below), I turn each course into an array, loop over it and print out each entry, I get the (second code set below) following:

```
response.setContentType("text/html");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
for (CourseJBean course : searchResults)   {
    String[] props = course.toArray();
    out.write("<br/>");
    for (String prop : props)   {
        out.write(prop + ",");
    }
} 
out.close();
```

produces

```
EC,EC134,E,4,MW, 1:00pm- 2:15pm,Principles of Macroeconomics,S, ,DIAM 141,21,35,15,Aguilar, laguilar,
EC,EC134,E,4,T, 3:00pm- 3:50pm,Principles of Macroeconomics,S, ,DIAM 141,21,35,15,Aguilar, laguilar,
EC,EC134,A,4,TR, 9:30am-10:45am,Principles of Macroeconomics,S, ,DIAM 141,35,35,15,Long, Jason.Long,
....... etc. (all 10 are here, with the correct data)
```

So the properties are being correctly put into the CourseJBean, and the array 'searchResults' correctly has the references to all 10 CourseJBeans, but yet it keeps telling me I have a String?

Sorry if that was more noise -- I've learned that it's better to have too much information than too little.

EDIT 2:

So the error I'm getting after cleaning out the  stuff and putting things into packages:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'id' not readable on type java.lang.String
    javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperty.read(BeanELResolver.java:291)
    javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperty.access$000(BeanELResolver.java:239)
    javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:85)
    javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:67)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169)
    org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:985)
    org.apache.jsp.HTML_002dJSP.searchResults_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(searchResults_jsp.java:211)
    org.apache.jsp.HTML_002dJSP.searchResults_jsp._jspService(searchResults_jsp.java:125)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:419)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    website.cirr_search.processRequest(cirr_search.java:113)
    website.cirr_search.doGet(cirr_search.java:128)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
```

There are only two lines I recognize, the ones with website.cirr_search (again, small project), and at line 113 in cirr_search is just

search.forward(request, response);

where 'search' is my results page (gotten via RequestDispatcher). Not sure why that would be a problem though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *So I'm trying to build a table based on the search results from a database access.*

You're using a [servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info), right?.

---

> *... so I have a javabean called CourseJBean ... I also have a javabean called searchJBean...*

Why not just a `List<Course>`?

---

> *I'm using JSP 2.0, JDK 1.6, and Java SE 6 on Netbeans 7.0 with an Apache 7 local server.*

Why not JSP 2.2? Tomcat 7 supports Servlet 3.0 / JSP 2.2.

---

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [cirr_search.do]

Are you using Struts?

---

> An exception occurred processing JSP page /HTML-JSP/searchResults.jsp at line 55
>
> ```
> 55:          ${course.id}
> ```
>
> root cause javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'id' not readable on type java.lang.String
>
> *I think this meant that it's retrieving 'course' as a String, not a CourseJBean*

That's correct. It can also be that `${requestScope.searchResults.courses}` returned a `String`.

---

> *I went with adding `<jsp:useBean>` tags:*

Oh please no.

---

> *Both CourseJBean.java and searchJBean.java reside in the default package (for now -- I'm learning).*

Never use the default package when you want to do a bit more than having a class with a `main()` method. Classes in the default package are invisble to classes inside a package. Classes inside a package cannot access or `import` classes in the default package. JSP/Servlet container itself exist of classes in a package and the generated JSP files are inside a package as well.

---

> An error occurred at line: 14 in the jsp file: /HTML-JSP/searchResults.jsp
>   searchJBean cannot be resolved to a type
>
> ```
> 14:         <jsp:useBean id="searchResults" scope="request" class="searchJBean"/>
> ```
>
> *What does this mean?*

The class is missing in the classpath (or it is simply invisible because it's in the default package).

---

> *What is a 'type'?*

A class, an interface or an enum. In your case, a class.

---

> *Do I need to use `<jsp:useBean>` tags even in JSP 2.0? Shouldn't it be able to find them?*

No you don't need them.

---

> *The original error -- why would I get a String?*

Because you supplied a String.

---

> *And most importantly, how do I fix this?*

Not sure. There's a lot of noise in the question, the real code of interest is missing. It should however not be *that* hard. You can find an example of how to create a search form with help of JSP and Servlet in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023596/using-servlets-and-html/2023704#2023704).

Comment: I tried to comment the below, but it was waaay too many characters.

Comment: Are `SearchJBean` and `CourseJBean` classes put in a real package (thus **not** default package) and are they a `public class`? (note `public`)

Comment: Well, I switched from the SearchJBean to just an ArrayList<CourseJBean>, which you recommended and was my initial plan, but yes, the CourseJBean is in a 'real' package and it is public.

Comment: Oh, and yes I'm using servlets, no Struts, and for all I know I am using JSP 2.2; all I know is that it's 2.x.

Comment: Solved -- apparently I didn't save an edit I made to my CourseJBean, and for the field 'id', I had getID(), not getId(). A lot of wasted time.